# Run ruby script when file appears in folder

Tags: ruby, automation, dropbox

I am working towards automating the running of my .rb script. Currently I have to go to terminal and type `ruby myscript`.

My plan, since I don't know exactly when the script will run each week/month, is to run the script when a file appears in a dropbox folder.

It would be something like this:

If `random_file.csv` is seen in the same folder as `myscript`,

`myscript` loads `random_file.csv`, does something with it, then saves `random_file.csv` in a separate folder and deletes it from the dropbox folder.

Is that possible, and if not, what are some good alternatives to automating scripts? Will I have to nail down a time to run it each week/month? Any guidance on what to look for is appreciated.

Comment: Yes possible! The way you think - the same can be automate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of automating dropbox files and folder is using the automator .  I found this link which allows you to set actions on your dropbox folder

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automate-dropbox-files-with-actions/

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

### Linux and Inotify

If you are on Linux, you can use the kernel's [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) system to create callbacks when a directory changes. When paired with the [rb-inotify gem](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify), you can configure a long-running script to perform some action when the IN_CREATE event is detected.

### Semaphores or Timestamps

A more complex solution involves checking file timestamps or checking directory contents for differences. As one example, you could use GNU find in conjunction with cron to execute a script whenever a file is newer than some number of minutes. For example,

```
# Run job every 5 minutes; execute on files less than 7 minutes old.
*/5 * * * * find /path/to/dropbox -cmin -7 -exec /path/to/ruby/script {} +
```

This isn't really idempotent, and there are all sorts of ways this can go horribly wrong, but it's the low-hanging fruit. Unless you don't have an inotify-like facility on your system, or can't daemonize your process, I'd save this sort of thing as a last resort. Still, it's always good to have options!